# Find nodes with cm:isIndexed = false

Tags: solr, alfresco

I am working on a large Alfresco installation where an unknown number of nodes have the aspect `cm:indexControl` and the property `cm:isIndexed` set to `false`. Of course, these nodes can not be found in a Solr search.

Is there a way to find all these nodes and remove aspect and property to trigger Solr to index them?

Comment: A possible solution would use [selectNodes()](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-selectNodes.html) with a XPath query like `//*[hasAspect('cm:indexControl') and @cm:isIndexed='false']`. I'll have to check if this works.

Comment: [NodeService.getChildAssocs](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildAssocs%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef%29) should return all nodes indexed or not, what about recursively processing all nodes and checking their aspects?

Comment: Well, the Alfresco installation contains some millions of documents. I'd prefer not to touch every node. So if possible I'd avoid walking the whole tree. Some search *without* Solr would be the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Alfrescos underlying database instead of walking the tree.
I have to admit it's a bit unorthodox, but definitely works.

In the first step you just need to find out some primary keys to ease your count query. 
The following little queries should help your to find the required information:
To find out the primary key of `cm:indexControl` aspect's qname use the following one. In my case it was `90`.

```
SELECT * FROM alfresco.alf_qname  WHERE local_name ="indexControl";
```

The `cm:isIndexed` property had the PK `89`.

```
SELECT * FROM alfresco.alf_qname  WHERE local_name ="isIndexed";
```

To get the PK of your `workspace://SpacesStore` store

```
SELECT * FROM alfresco.alf_store;
```

I assume the `workspace://SpacesStore` has the PK `6`.

Now the preparation is done, you should have all required information and can trigger the query that counts all nodes that have a `cm:indexControl` aspect with a `cm:isIndexed` property set to false and located in the `workspace://SpacesStore` store.

```
SELECT Distinct count(*) FROM alfresco.alf_node_aspects a, alfresco.alf_node n, alf_node_properties p 
WHERE a.qname_id=90 
AND a.node_id = n.id 
AND p.node_id = n.id
AND p.boolean_value=0
AND p.qname_id =89
AND n.store_id = 6;
```